# TRIM based on a condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following statement. I am trying to use the CASE function to remove the "COD - " in front of any account names that start with "COD - "

```
SELECT
     DCLink
   , CASE
         WHEN LEFT(Client.Account, 6) = 'COD - ' THEN LTRIM(Client.Account)
         ELSE Client.Account
     END AS CustName
   , Client.Name AS AccName
   , Client.Contact_Person
   , Client.Telephone AS Telephone_1
   , Client.Telephone2 AS Telephone_2
   , Client.Fax1 AS Fax_1
   , Client.Fax2 AS Fax_2
   , Client.Tax_Number AS VATNumber
   , Client.EMail
   , SalesRep.Code
   , SalesRep.Name
   , CONCAT(Client.Physical1, ' ', Client.Physical2, ' ', Client.Physical3, ' ', Client.Physical4, ' ', Client.Physical5, ' ', Client.PhysicalPC) AS CustPhysical
   , CONCAT(Client.Post1, ' ', Client.Post2, ' ', Client.Post3, ' ', Client.Post4, ' ', Client.Post5, ' ', Client.PostPC) AS CustPost
FROM Client
INNER JOIN SalesRep ON SalesRep.idSalesRep = Client.RepID
```

I feel like I am just missing a simple step here?

In other words, in the database there may be the following two customer account names:

- Wonderful Sweets Ltd
- COD - Thirsty Beverages Ltd

I want to say that if the account name begins with the string "COD - ", it must remove that part.

Comment: REPLACE (Client.Account, 'COD - ', '')

Comment: LTRIM only remove the spaces in the left side. it doesnt remove characters.

Comment: Thank you! Replace worked Perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
     DCLink
   , REPLACE(Client.Account,'COD - ','') AS CustName
   , Client.Name AS AccName
   , Client.Contact_Person
   , Client.Telephone AS Telephone_1
   , Client.Telephone2 AS Telephone_2
   , Client.Fax1 AS Fax_1
   , Client.Fax2 AS Fax_2
   , Client.Tax_Number AS VATNumber
   , Client.EMail
   , SalesRep.Code
   , SalesRep.Name
   , CONCAT(Client.Physical1, ' ', Client.Physical2, ' ', Client.Physical3, ' ', Client.Physical4, ' ', Client.Physical5, ' ', Client.PhysicalPC) AS CustPhysical
   , CONCAT(Client.Post1, ' ', Client.Post2, ' ', Client.Post3, ' ', Client.Post4, ' ', Client.Post5, ' ', Client.PostPC) AS CustPost
FROM Client
INNER JOIN SalesRep ON SalesRep.idSalesRep = Client.RepID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a replace statement to replace 'COD' with any value you want to.
Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms186862.aspx